# enum_in.Single() is 1 and throws exception

Tags: c#, linq

I m executing the follwing code:

```
private static T FooException<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enum_in)    
{    
    try    
    {
        return enum_in.Single();
    }    
    catch(InvalidOperationException e)    
    {
        throw new XXXException(enum_in.Count(),  e   ...
    }    
}
```

and getting an `InvalidOperationException`.
If I have a look at `enum.Count()` then ther is exactly one item.
Thats what I don't understand. Are there any cases where the enum can be with count = 1
and running in `InvalidOperationException`?

Comment: Can you show us reproducible sample data?

Comment: Is that `enum.Count()` or `enum_in.Count()`?

Comment: It all depends how `IEnumerable<T>` is implemented. Can you show us a failing implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`? Or, what class are you calling you `FooException` extension on?

Comment: @Jodrell: If that would not be a simple typo, it would not even compile.

Comment: @Tim - unless the OP has both `enum_in` and `enum` on the same scope, which can explain why one has a count of 1, and the other throws an exception. I guess it's possible, but very unlikely.

Comment: It is a typo enum_in.Count()  not enum.count()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all implementations of Linq support all operations. Try using `.First()` instead.

Edit: To answer the comments about this not being true. Firstly, we don't know the concrete class of the variable, so even if you don't know of any implementation for which Single is unsupported, that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Furthermore I was thinking of the LINQ-To-Entity implementation. My source was the [Microsoft Press book for exam 70-516](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627398), which on page 423 states that there are some unsupported methods connected to paging:

> **Paging** A paging operation returns a single, specific element from a sequence. The supported methods are First, FirstOrDefault, Skip and Take. The unsupported methods are ElementAt, ElementAtOrDefault, Last, LastOrDefault, ***Single***, SingleOrDefault, SkipWhile and TakeWhile.

All of the examples also use First rather than Single in that chapter, which is why I took extra note of this. It's interresting that this contradicts the msdn documentation linked in the comments.

Comment: Sorry Mithon, that is not right, First and Single are different. If your enumerable contains multiple items, first will just give you the first item, whereas Single() will thrown an exception, which could be what you want.

Comment: Well, linq to SQL or Entity Framework does not support `Single`, if I remember correctly, but here we have an `IEnumerable`, so it looks like linq to objects.

Comment: Nopes, this is not wrong. It seems Kobi did also read the book. I didn't say Single and First has the exact same behaviour, but you can use First when Single doesn't exist. If you need to assert that Count()==1, you can do that before you call First.

Comment: @Mithon: [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156472.aspx) is also supported in Linq-To-Sql and Linq-To-Entities. Here's the list of supported operators: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter I can't recall which variant didn't support it. Will have to look it up. Don't have the resouce with me, so will have to wait a few. Could be Linq-To-XML for all I remember. Or maybe Linq-to-entities now support it, but didn't previously.. Like I said.. I'll have to check.

Comment: Ok. Now see my updated answer. @Downvoter why would you downvote the only constructive answer which might potentially hold a solution, and keep the other answers which states the obvious or are simple comments?

Comment: @Mithon: This answers my questions, that there are any cases. Thanks for investigation. The error pops up sporadically and therfore I will check the type and then try First() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Single throws an InvalidOperationException if the enumerable is empty or the sequence contains more than one element. What do you get if you call SingleOrDefault()?

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb155325.aspx) says

InvalidOperationException

The input sequence contains more than one element.

-or-

The input sequence is empty.

So I guess either you or MSDN is wrong. Did you try SingleOrDefault too? Maybe it is null.